# how to insert multi textbox array in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to ruby. i need insert the array textbox values to has_many and belongs_to relationship.i used two models intrrattes and intrsetups.

here is my new.html.erb file

```
<%= form_for @intrsetup do |f| %>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='span6'>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class=" control-label">Effective From<abbr     title="required">*</abbr></label>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :effective_from, :onclick => "return calender()" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='span6'>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class=" control-label">Effective To</label>
        <div   class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :effective_to %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<%= f.fields_for :intrrates do |builder| %>



<h3>Interest Rates</h3>
  <table class='table condensed-table'>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Days From
    </td>
    <td>
    Days To
    </td>
    <td>
    Rate
    </td>
    <td>
    Senior Increment
    </td>
    <td>
    Super Senior Increment
    </td>
    <td>
    Widow Increment
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>



 <%(1..2).each do |i|%>
    <%= builder.text_field(:days_from, :name => "intrrate[days_from][]", :id =>    "intrrate_days_from_#{i}") %>
    <%end%>
```

<%= builder.text_field :days_to, multiple: true %>
        
        
        <%= builder.text_field :rate, multiple: true %>
        
        
        <%= builder.text_field :senior_increment %>
        
        
        <%= builder.text_field :super_senior_increment %>
        
        
        <%= builder.text_field :widow_increment %>
        
        
        <% end %>
        
         <%= f.submit %>

here is my Intrrate and Intrsetup  model code

```
class Intrrate < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :intrsetup
#attr_accessor :effective_from, :effective_to
attr_accessible :effective_from, :effective_to
attr_accessible :days_from, :days_to, :rate, :senior_increment, :super_senior_increment,   :widow_increment, :intrsetup_id
end

class Intrsetup < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :intrrates
accepts_nested_attributes_for :intrrates
attr_accessible :intrrates_id, :effective_from, :effective_to, :intrrates_attributes    
end
```

here is my controller page

```
class IntrsetupsController < ApplicationController
def new
@intrsetup = Intrsetup.new
@intrrate = @intrsetup.intrrates.build
end
def create
@intrsetup = Intrsetup.new(params["intrsetup"])
@intrsetup.save
end
end

class IntrratesController < ApplicationController
def index
@intrrate = Intrrate.all
end

def new
@intrrate = Intrrate.new
end

def create
puts @intrrate = Intrrate.new(params["intrrate"])
@intrrate.save
end
end
```

my schema.rb

```
create_table "intrrates", :force => true do |t|
t.integer  "days_from"
t.integer  "days_to"
t.float    "rate"
t.float    "senior_increment"
t.float    "super_senior_increment"
t.float    "widow_increment"
t.datetime "created_at",             :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",             :null => false
t.integer  "intrsetup_id"
t.integer  "deposit_id"
end

create_table "intrsetups", :force => true do |t|
t.date     "effective_from"
t.date     "effective_to"
t.datetime "created_at",     :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",     :null => false
end
```

my error page
    NoMethodError in IntrsetupsController#create

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: /home/tbf/rails_projects/ccddeposit

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/intrsetups_controller.rb:9:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"WsfTU31o9LLfcoieNL3pgpRRu/swqreaXDdo6LxrdsM=",
"intrsetup"=>{"effective_from"=>"1994/12/06",
"effective_to"=>"1994/12/06"},
"intrrate_days_from_1"=>"1",
"intrrate_days_to_1"=>"45",
"intrrate_rate_1"=>"0.5",
"intrrate_senior_increment_1"=>"0.5",
"intrrate_super_senior_increment_1"=>"0.56",
"intrrate_widow_increment_1"=>"0.5",
"intrrate_days_from_2"=>"45",
"intrrate_days_to_2"=>"95",
"intrrate_rate_2"=>"0.5",
"intrrate_senior_increment_2"=>"0.7",
"intrrate_super_senior_increment_2"=>"0.8",
"intrrate_widow_increment_2"=>"0.5",
"commit"=>"Create Intrsetup"}
but i'm getting the following error
```

how to solve this error?

Comment: show some code of your `method`

Comment: @nithin: i have edited my code check it.

Comment: At which line you are getting that error?

Comment: @Pavan: i'm guessing this line <%(1..2).each do |i|%>
<%= builder.text_field(:days_from, :name => "intrrate[days_from][]", :id =>    "intrrate_days_from_#{i}") %>
<%end%>

Comment: @Pavan:i'm getting the following error line.NoMethodError in IntrsetupsController#create

undefined method `to_f' for ["5.2"]:Array

Comment: Can you post the full error message with the stacktrace in the question?

Comment: @Pavan:NoMethodError in IntrsetupsController#create

undefined method `to_f' for ["5.2"]:Array

Comment: Hi - that's not a full stacktrace... which usually has about 50 lines... can you please post that in your *question* (because comment formatting is always awful). Also - proper indentation of your code really helps readability (and thus finding hidden bugs) thanks :)

Comment: @TarynEast:NoMethodError in IntrsetupsController#create

undefined method `to_f' for ["5.2"]:Array how to solve this error?

Comment: This is *NOT* the full stacktrace. This is a single line from the top of the stacktrace. The full stacktrace is 50 lines long. Where are you getting this error (on what screen after you do what exactly?). Does it show up in the browser? or in your logs? or where?

Comment: @TarynEast: I have edited my code page.check it(added error page)

Comment: @TarynEast:please reply me

Comment: You have this error because you receive and array in `"rate"` parameter and you try to convert this Array into a float and it is not possible. You have to get the value IN your array and convert this value after.

Comment: Hi @user3687538 - looks like you've got some great help from Kilian. I wasn't replying because I have other work to do too... ;) Don't forget that everybody on Stack Overflow is on here for free using their own spare time... they are unlikely to reply to you quickly.

Comment: @TarynEast: it's okay

Comment: @TarynEast: how to set the dynamic dropdown with textbox in two models?kindly help me.

Comment: Ok... my very first thing I ever do when presented with code like yours is to try to properly indent it. Neat and tidy code makes it easy to spot errors... and your code has them... but you can't see them, because it isn't indented properly. I recommend that you go to your code and indent it. Every time a tag is opened, you indent by two spaces. Every time you close a tag - you un-indent by two spaces... you will find at least one bug in your template that way. I wont' tell you what it is... because this is an exercise in showing you why you should *always* properly indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, the problem is `rate` is attending a float and you give to it an Array.

So here is a code which force your parameter "rate" as a float value and give you the average of all rates entered in your form :

```
def create
  # In case where you want the average value of all different rates you enter in your form
  rate_avg = params["intrsetup"]["intrrates_attributes"]["0"]["rate"].inject(0.0) do |value, rate|
    value += rate.to_f
  end
  params["intrsetup"]["intrrates_attributes"]["0"]["rate"] = rate_avg / params["intrsetup"]["intrrates_attributes"]["0"]["rate"].count
  @intrsetup = Intrsetup.new(params["intrsetup"])
  @intrsetup.save
end
```

Try this and tell me if it works now.

Comment: doesn't work the create method.rate field only for intrrates table not for intrsetups.but you given the code for intrsetups table

Comment: My bad, I read too fast your params. But your error is on `intrsetups` saving and it's because you send the params with `intrrates` attributes inside. And the problem is you try to convert an Array into a float. So I edit my answer and maybe you can try it again.

Comment: :okay thanks.all parameters value passed.but it shows the error:NoMethodError in IntrsetupsController#create

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Yeah that means I do a mistake again... Sorry about that, I put `paramsparams` instead of `params` on line 6 of my `create` method. I will be more careful.

Comment: Do you change your form ? Because your params are not the same than before.

Comment: how to set dynamic dropdown with textbox in two models using rails